# How can I make this horizontal accordion's tabs close upon a second click?

Tags: jquery

So I have this horizontal slider that I've modified to fit my needs, and some of the DOM traversal stuff the author did gets a little confusing. What I'm trying to accomplish is making the tabs being 'close-able' so that once the tabs are opened they can be reverted to their previous state by being clicked again. I feel like this should be really easy but everything I've tried by messing with the jQuery has resulted in various bugs.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GxFan/8/

This is the basic mechanism of the accordion:

```
$("div.slide div.handle").click(function () {

    if ($(this).parent("div.slide").hasClass("opened")) {

        $(this).siblings().css({
            "opacity": "1"
        });
        var e = $(this).parent("div.slide");
        var p = e.prevAll("div.slide.opened");
        var ph = p.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
        var pi = p.children("div.inside");
        //e.children("div.inside").animate({"margin-left":"-883px"}, 1000);
        pi.animate({
            "margin-left": "-400px"
        }, 800, function () {
            ph.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)");
            //e.css({"width":"39px"});
            pi.css({
                "width": "39px"
            });
            //e.children("div.inside").css({"width":"0px", "margin-left":"0px"});
            pi.css({
                "width": "0px",
                "margin-left": "0px"
            });
            //e.removeClass("opened");
            p.removeClass("opened");
        });
        //e.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img").animate({rotate: '+=180deg'}, 1000);
        ph.rotate('0deg');

    } else {
        $(this).siblings().css({
            "opacity": "1"
        });
        var e = $(this).parent("div.slide");
        var n = e.nextAll("div.slide:not(.opened)");
        var ei = e.children("div.inside");
        var ni = n.children("div.inside");
        var eh = e.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
        var nh = n.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
        $(this).parent("div.slide").siblings().children('.inside').css({
            "opacity": "0"
        });
        e.css({
            "width": "270px"
        });
        n.css({
            "width": "270px"
        });
        ei.animate({
            "width": "230px",
            "margin-left": "0px"
        }, 800);
        ni.animate({
            "width": "230px",
            "margin-left": "0px"
        }, 800);
        eh.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)");
        nh.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)");
        eh.rotate('180deg');
        nh.rotate('180deg');
        e.addClass("opened");
        n.addClass("opened");
        e.addClass("opened2");
        n.addClass("opened2");

        $(".initial-image").clearQueue().stop(true, false);
    }
```

Thanks so much in advance to anyone who can provide me with some insight, and I apologize if this isn't the right place for this.

Best,
Cooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is what you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/GxFan/12/)

I had to add another if statement and use your thought of an added `opened2` class to get it functioning

Here is the updated jQuery

```
 $(function () {

    $("div.slide div.handle").click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent("div.slide").hasClass("opened") && !$(this).parent("div.slide").hasClass("opened2")) {
            $(this).siblings().css({
                "opacity": "1"
            });
            var e = $(this).parent("div.slide");
            var p = e.prevAll("div.slide.opened");
            var ph = p.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
            var pi = p.children("div.inside");
            //e.children("div.inside").animate({"margin-left":"-883px"}, 1000);
            pi.animate({
                "margin-left": "-400px"
            }, 800, function () {
                ph.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)");
                //e.css({"width":"39px"});
                pi.css({
                    "width": "39px"
                });
                //e.children("div.inside").css({"width":"0px", "margin-left":"0px"});
                pi.css({
                    "width": "0px",
                        "margin-left": "0px"
                });
                //e.removeClass("opened");
                p.removeClass("opened");
            });
            //e.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img").animate({rotate: '+=180deg'}, 1000);
            ph.rotate('0deg');
            $(this).parent("div.slide").addClass("opened2");
            $(this).parent("div.slide").siblings().removeClass("opened2");

        } else if ($(this).parent("div.slide").hasClass("opened2")) {
            $(this).parent("div.slide").removeClass("opened2");
            $(this).siblings().css({
                "opacity": "1"
            });
            var e = $(this).parent("div.slide");
            var p = e.prevAll("div.slide.opened").andSelf();
            var ph = p.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
            var pi = p.children("div.inside");
            //e.children("div.inside").animate({"margin-left":"-883px"}, 1000);
            pi.animate({
                "margin-left": "-400px"
            }, 800, function () {
                ph.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)");
                //e.css({"width":"39px"});
                pi.css({
                    "width": "39px"
                });
                //e.children("div.inside").css({"width":"0px", "margin-left":"0px"});
                pi.css({
                    "width": "0px",
                        "margin-left": "0px"
                });
                //e.removeClass("opened");
                p.removeClass("opened");
            });
            //e.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img").animate({rotate: '+=180deg'}, 1000);
            ph.rotate('0deg');
            var next = $(this).parent("div.slide").next("div.slide");
            if (next.length > 0) {
                next.addClass("opened2").children("div.inside").css({
                    "opacity": "1"
                });
            }
        } else {
            $(this).siblings().css({
                "opacity": "1"
            });
            var e = $(this).parent("div.slide");
            var n = e.nextAll("div.slide:not(.opened)");
            var ei = e.children("div.inside");
            var ni = n.children("div.inside");
            var eh = e.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
            var nh = n.children("div.handle").children('.handle-arrow').children("img");
            $(this).parent("div.slide").siblings().children('.inside').css({
                "opacity": "0"
            });
            e.css({
                "width": "270px"
            });
            n.css({
                "width": "270px"
            });
            ei.animate({
                "width": "230px",
                    "margin-left": "0px"
            }, 800);
            ni.animate({
                "width": "230px",
                    "margin-left": "0px"
            }, 800);
            eh.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)");
            nh.css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)");
            eh.rotate('180deg');
            nh.rotate('180deg');
            e.addClass("opened");
            n.addClass("opened");
            $(this).parent("div.slide").addClass("opened2");
            $(this).parent("div.slide").siblings().removeClass("opened2");

            $(".initial-image").clearQueue().stop(true, false);
        }
    });

});
```

The arrows are not functioning perfectly in your or my versions, but that's for another question (or more preferably for you to fix yourself)

I might also recommend animating the opacity of the `.inside`s being shown/removed if it works well. It'd just take changing the relevant `.css`es to `.animate`s

It did break a couple times for me, though I can't find out why

**Note**: For new versions of jQuery you need to change `.andSelf()` to `.addBack()`

Comment: You are amazing, thank you! I found the solution eventually, but couldn't figure out why it was breaking for newer versions of jQuery so that is super helpful as well... I'm taking in all the DOM stuff bit by bit... Here is the fork I came up with, with mostly working arrows:

http://jsfiddle.net/GxFan/15/

For some reason they do bug out a little from time to time.